# Tomcat error 404: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am trying to deploy a simple Jax- RS application with apache Tomcat. The server is running correctly on my localhost, the tomcat homepage is up. But when I run from eclipse on my server i get a status 404 error. Does anyone know why this is?

Pom.xml

```
    project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.javaee8</groupId>
      <artifactId>hello-javaee8</artifactId>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>hello-javaee8 Maven Webapp</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


      <dependencies>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>8.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <finalName>hello-javaee8</finalName>
      </build>
    </project>
```

Web.xml

```
    <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
     "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
     "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

    <web-app>
      <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    </web-app>
```

If there is any other file I need to add to find this solution let me know

Comment: [1] Update your question to specify what you submit from the browser to get a 404. [2] Provide a full listing of pom.xml. What you are showing currently is not valid.

Comment: Did my solution work for you? If so please select the green check mark

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons.

First of all, you are not including a JAX-RS implementation, only the JAX-RS API. The JAX-RS API only provides a set of interfaces, and leaves it up to the implementation to provide concrete implementations of those interfaces.

If you do not have a JAX-RS implementation, I would advise you to go with Jersey (the reference implementation). Add the following to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.29</version>
</dependency>
```

Secondly, you have not registered your application anywhere in the `web.xml`. How you do this depends on what JAX-RS implementation you use and how you register your classes and providers. To help you with this I need you to answer a few questions:

1. Do you have a class implementing `Application` (or a class extending `ResourceConfig`)?
2. Are all your resource classes annotated with `@Path` and all your providers annotated with `@Provider`?
3. Are all your resource classes and providers in the same package?
4. What JAX-RS implementation are you going with?

If you use Jersey and answered yes to the first question, place the following in `web.xml`:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</filter-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value><!-- FQN of your Application/ResourceConfig class --></param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Otherwise, look at the setup instructions for your specific JAX-RS framework.